# Strategies for learning and writing code when I'm not allowed to be "polluted" with open source code?

Tags: open-source, licensing

I work at a company where the rule basically is (as I understand it) that you cannot use any code unless (a) you write the code yourself or (b) there is some explicit indemnification clause guarding your use of any other code (like open source code). I am finding this making my coding difficult.

For example, coding samples in books are pretty much use "as-is". Microsoft SDK Code Samples are use "as-is". Blog posts about coding are use "as-is". There are several sites out there with code samples (including SO) that are use at your own risk. No warranties implied or indemnification against intellectual property lawsuits, blah, blah, etc.

Basically, I'm confined to using Asp.Net and the .Net Framework and nothing else and to bar my eyes from accidentally picking something up that I haven't created (ok...that may be my anal interpretation of the rule ;-).

I find this difficult because a big part of learning to code I think is reading other code. Reading blogs that have code, reading books that have code, looking at coding samples, using code from SDK samples etc. Also, I would think it is safe to use code that people have shown to be a good solution or pattern for something and freely put up for others to use. I'm not about to think that I can code everything myself. I definitely have to stand on the coding shoulders of others to reach certain heights.

It could be that I don't understand licensing very well either. From the companie's perspective (I suppose) they don't want to incur any risk of beind sued for IP infringement.

My thought is that you have to weigh risks. Taking a coding snippet from a book is low risk. Incorporating code from an open source library could be high-risk. I say make decisions based on how much risk you are willing to take.

Has anybody had experience working in a situation like this or similar to this? Is this a rare thing or is it common in some sectors? Are there others in the same position like me out there?

Any insight or guidance would be appreciated! Thanks!

**Edit:**
Thanks for the responses! To clear up some things: I'm not advocating stealing code. I'm talking about code that has some kind of public license that allows it to be used in its defined legal way. The key is there is no ***indemnification*** in public licenses in using the code. That means it you use it at your own *legal* risk (and other risk). If someone sues an open source project that you used code from, you could be roped into the lawsuit as well because you are using the code even though it had a public license.

In 2005, Microsoft was using indemnification to compete against open source venders by promising it's partners that Microsoft would protect them against IP lawsuits. http://www.microsoft.com/presspass/press/2005/jun05/06-22PartnerIndemnificationPR.mspx

So, even if the risk of being sued for IP infringement may be extremely low, it is a non-zero probability. Thus, I can't use any of it. Even if it has a public license of some sort. :-(

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because **it is about licensing or legal issues**, not programming or software development. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/274964/1402846) for details, and the [help/on-topic] for more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By "indemnification", I assume they mean assurance that the code is free of copyright or patent or maybe trade secret encumbrance that they don't know about up front, or that somebody's willing to compensate them if something like that turns up.  I've never been in a company that worried about this, nor have I heard of one before.

It's not clear what you actually want here, other than sympathy (and I do have sympathy for people trapped in corporate foolishness).  It sounds like the policy is quite rigid, if you're worried about sample code in books.  This is a bad policy, and will hinder you, but I don't know what you can do about it.  Unlike Joel's blog post on getting things done as a grunt, it sounds like you can't just start doing thing intelligently without being in clear violation of corporate policy.

Not knowing your situation, my suggestion would be to look for another job.  This one will definitely stifle your professional growth, and a company with that policy is unlikely to be reasonable about it.

(It would be nice if you could assure them there was no danger, but that's not true.  People have lied about copyrights, although open source projects tend not to, and only a fool would claim definitely that a large chunk of code did not infringe on any patents in the US; even if it was written a year before software patents were first awarded, that would be merely good grounds for a court fight, rather than avoiding a court fight.  GPLed software is actually better than BSD software, since it requires some patent licensing downstream, but it can't deal with third-party patents.  Of course, if they're that worried about being sued, writing in-house software is no solution.  That can infringe on patents.)

Comment: You are right about the indemnification. And probably about the sympathy part as well. ;-) I'm attempting a grunt movement and trying to educate. My first attempt is to take the policy literally (which makes it exclude books, blog posts, sample code, etc.) to show that it is way too restrictive.

Answer (score 5):

The "risk of beind sued for IP infringement" isn't really the right way to think about it.  This isn't a "risk" thing.

Either

- You have a license and can use the source.  There's no risk.  You have the license.  There can't be a lawsuit.

Or

- You don't have a license and you're in violation.  Effectively, you *will* be sued.  There's no risk here, either.  You're in violation of someone's copyrights (or worse).

Companies are averse to Open Source for a variety of strange reasons.  Risk of lawsuit is not one of them.

Things I've heard.

- What if it has a virus?
- What if it doesn't work as advertised?
- What if it "crashes" something?  Who do we sue?

None of these are "risk" items.  They're "due diligence" items.  And mostly, they're easy to address: pick products with enough users that someone else vets the code before you;  QA open source as if one of your own people typed it in.  Except for one.

This leads us to the real reason.  [Hint: It's not "risk of lawsuit".]

**There's no one to sue when you didn't perform due diligence on open source.**

Most shops don't have real solid configuration management or QA policies (the kind that would stand up in court as best practices).  Until they have these things in place, they don't dare think about introducing open source for which you really need solid QA and configuration management.

Comment: There is a risk of being sued even if you have a license. Some lawyers have nothing better to do than to write up some lies and misinformation in order to intimidate people who actually have licenses, causing massive amounts of extra work and legal fees.

Comment: @dontomaso: You have that backwards.  It's not the risk of being sued.  It's user organization's lawyers not knowing who they can sue.  If an open source product fails, the user organization's lawyer cannot sue anyone.  There's no "enterprise" with legal representation that the user of open source software can sue.  Except in rare cases where there's an Apache Foundation.

Answer (score 2):

I think what your company is really worried about is you directly copying large segments of code for which there may be licensing issues, presenting a legal problem to the company if they are caught using it. However, you may read blogs or other non-licensed code and discover a solution which works for the particular problem you are working on. In that case, you would be better off rewriting the code (that is, look at the solution and reproduce it) as opposed to just copying the code and making modifications to it. At my company, that is what they generally recommend for using non-proprietary code.

As well, for small amounts of code (e.g. a standard implementation of a cache) where everyone implements this the same way, every time, your company is unlikely to be afraid of using outside code, as long as you are sure to test it carefully.

Answer (score 0):

You could rename the variables and how would they find out? Do they check every line of code ? Universities tell you that all the time, not to copy code without referencing. Why don't you try coding something and useing parts of code you find in the Internet?

Generally you will use more from communities like stack overflow or blogs than from open source projects.

Finally since the code has no warranties, its at your own risk.. well the is the same case if you came up with the code by yourself: its at your own risk.

Hope that helps... and good luck.

Answer (score 0):

> It could be that I don't understand licensing very well either. From the companie's perspective (I suppose) they don't want to incur any risk of beind sued for IP infringement.
>
> My thought is that you have to weigh risks. Taking a coding snippet from a book is low risk. Incorporating code from an open source library could be high-risk. I say make decisions based on how much risk you are willing to take.

I'm not sure if I understood correctly. If you are saying that license infringement is fine when you don't get caught, I will have to disagree with you.

You can learn by reading code without breaking laws or getting fired. Just don't copy the code to your company's code base if the license doesn't allow it.

Answer (score 0):

If you're not aware of the "clean room" concept, then there's always that approach.  Have a friend look at some open source code and get them to tell you how they think it works.  Diagram it out, and then code it yourself.

If it worked for IBM, right?

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that not all Open Source is GPL. Your company can copy as much BSD-licensed code as they like. BSD-licensed code has made it into OS X (that's probably my biggest understatement of today) and to a lesser extent Windows NT.